# Use querySelector in nativescript;

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i want to play an animation when a new message is added in the DOM.

but i don't know how to find my object and edit it with code in (this.zone.run) function :

```
addMessage(message: string){
    this.messages.unshift(message);
    // renderer
    this.zone.run(() => {

    });
}
```

here's the app.component.html

```
<StackLayout #container>
    <ScrollView>
        <WrapLayout #red>
            <Label class="message" *ngFor="let message of messages" [text]="message"></Label>
        </WrapLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

i want to edit the first child of the WrapLayout element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DOM with NativeScript.

However a major community contributor wrote a plugin to help transition web developers into native development with NativeScript. This plugin provides helper methods that you'll find familiar to the web and DOM. https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom

Just remember these are helper methods are not something provided out of the box by NativeScript. You can get any view by its id in NativeScript several ways and during different events (page/frame and component level).

I recall there's no page component with NativeScript with angular but I think you still have the frame module which you could do something like

`frame.topmost().currentPage.getViewById('yourID');`

Making sure you import(require) the frame module.